# Is it possible to use $_SESSION in sockets in php?

Tags: php, sockets, session

```
   <?php 
    session_start();
    .
    .
    $response = mask(json_encode(array('type'=>'system', 'message'=>$_SESSION['name'].' user has joined'))); //prepare json data
    send_message($response); //notify all users about new connection
    .
    .
    ?>
```

However while i am starting my socket server in my localhost using my cmd it gives me the error 
Undefined index 'name'
But i am quite sure that session has been set perfectly !
**So basically i want to know is whether i can use session variables in socket using php ! yes or no ?**
*Thank you in advance*

Comment: Not out of the box, no. You can program your own session management, but sessions do not work in CLI and definitely not with your *clients* as the session part of PHP has no clue that you're using sockets. That said, making your own session management interface shouldn't be too hard. Just have your users send some sort of session ID when they're connecting.

Comment: Thank you for such a quick response !
can you give me some quick links where in i can learn about session management !